# How to put a VB.net console application to task scheduler 

Tags: vb.net, scheduling, scheduled-tasks

I would like to ask on how to put vb.net console application program to task scheduler so that the program will run automatically without manipulation. The program will fetch data to a database and insert it to mysql. There should be a trigger every 1 hr or something to get the data. Any suggestions on how to run it without any error?

Is there any way on how to put console application to the task scheduler in windows?
I would be grateful for any suggestions. thanks in advance

Comment: http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Comment: thank you. should it be put in the program? Is there other way around to run it? @CodyGray

Comment: Well, the point is that you have to use the COM-based APIs (provided by Windows) to schedule your app in the task scheduler. The linked library is a set of wrappers around that native API to make it friendlier to use from .NET applications. Since that's written in C# and your project is in VB.NET, you probably want to just add a reference to the DLL for that library to your app so that you can make use of its functions.

Comment: Is this the easiest way @CodyGray? Im not familiar with COM-based APIs. any sample? on how to make use of it? much appreciated. thanks a lot